# How to edit physical file record on AS/400 by using STRSQL

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I just got a new laptop with Windows 10 which can't use the "Data Transfer to iSeries" function in excel. I've tried to re-install the add-on again but still does not work.

I'd like to transfer file which has a list of objects, libraries, and saved date for restoration on AS/400 (using BRMS function) 
For example :

```
   OBJ          LIB1        LIB2        DATE
   OBJ0001      FROMLIB01   TOLIB01     20/12/2018
   OBJ0002      FROMLIB02   TOLIB02     20/12/2018
   OBJ0003      FROMLIB03   TOLIB03     20/12/2018
```

So, I need to find the way to edit record in the physical file instead of transferring the file from the PC. I know that STRSQL can edit records but I'm not familiar with the SQL commands. Can anyone guide me on how to edit many records using SQL?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly about AS/400 but about SQL in General. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_syntax) for a general overview of the syntax and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-quick-guide.htm) for a quick start guide.

For changing records (on the AS/400), the standard UPDATE clause applies. Probably you're not aware that the F4 prompting function also works in interactive SQL (strsql). Try it out, it's definitely helpful for a beginner.

A general starting statement would be `UPDATE LIBRARY/TABLENAME SET field1='value1', … WHERE field1='value0'…`

The SET Clause lists comma-separated field-value pairs to write (update) and the WHERE clause restricts these updates to the desired records. The WHERE-Clause can be made arbitrarily complex and list many restrictions with AND/OR boolean logic for precise selection of which records to update. See tutorial for WHERE-Clause examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for your sharing. I've tried to insert record to PF by using STRSQL and it's work, then i tried to use SQL command in my CL program because i need to insert too many record, after compiled and call PGM, The job log tell about "Member OBJ0001 not journaled to journal *N". I use DSPFD to see file attribute and i found that " File is currently journaled . . . . . . . . :            No".          
Do i have to change my PF attribute which attached with journal?  How to change this value?

Comment: I'm not fluent with Journalling on this platform. It would be probably more helpful if you check WRKJRN and WRKJRNA. Maybe see also RUNSQLSTM for bulk-INSERTs.